# How to assign double quote in c# variable

Tags: c#

I want assign following string to `foo` variable but i cant write it since it contains multiple `"` charecters. How can i assign this text in this variable without removing `"`

```
string foo = @"<span class="stat"><span class="green">$208.95</span></span>";
```

Comment: You have to escape the `"` using: `\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape by double-double quoting:

```
string foo = @"<span class=""stat""><span class=""green"">$208.95</span></span>";
```